# Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in use-google-libraries.php on line 335 wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am encountering a PHP > 5.4 error on my wordpress plugin

```
Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in 
wp-content\plugins\use-google-libraries\use-google-libraries.php on line 335
```

BUT line 335 starts like this:

```
if ( wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( wp_remote_head( "http:$url" ) ) !== 200 ) {
    self::debug( "Google servers do not seem to be hosting requested version of $name (version $ver). Using version provided by WordPress." );
    continue;
}
```

I know that passing by reference is done something like `=&` but I don't see any signs like those. Plugin is: https://wordpress.org/plugins/use-google-libraries/
I really searched regarding this but did not find anything and want to fix this issue.

Comment: There are 3 functions being used - `wp_remote_retrieve_response_code`, `wp_remote_head` and `self::debug`. Since I'm lazy to go check the plugin and I absolutely can't stand Wordpress' code, I can only suggest to invoke functions by passing variables to them in this way: `if ( wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( ( $head = wp_remote_head( "http:$url" ) ) ) !== 200 )` and `self::debug( $message = "Google servers do not seem to be hosting requested version of $name (version $ver). Using version provided by WordPress." );`. It might fix the message.

Comment: ok error is somehow back, and I can see it in the wp-login.php

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the file. Plugin wasn't updated in the last year and may encounter other problems too.

Change `wp_remote_head` to `wp_remote_get` manually. I think it will solve the issue.

Comment: Your help is much appreciated. I can see the error still in wp-login.php.